# Can't compile okhttp with jack enabled

Tags: android, okhttp, android-jack-and-jill

My project was working great but then i decided to enable jack, after this i got the following error:

**The type com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath**.

I'm using build tools 25.0.1 and my gradle dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

Please note that if i disable again jack the project works.